# How to calculate per CPU load

Tags: linux, cpu

Is there any C API to calculate per CPU load? `/proc/loadavg` gives the CPU average load for all available CPUs and `/proc/stat` doesn't mention anything about active processes per CPU.

How can I obtain the load per CPU?

Comment: Did you try `man proc 5` to see if there is anything else? I couldn't find it with a quick look, but you may have better luck. I would think it is somewhere hidden there, as the system monitor nicely shows what you want (I think).

Comment: yes I looked at man proc 5 it gives me information about the each process but I am looking at the aggregated CPU load. is there any file where per CPU load is updated? that will also suffice my problem

Comment: The load is not usually kept per CPU, since the run queue is a single entity (or at least was when I browsed through the relevant code).

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing as per-CPU load.

Load average is defined as the number of processes waiting on system resources. This isn't necessarily CPU. Also since a process might be waiting on CPU time, and isn't actively running on a CPU, you can't attribute it to any particular CPU since the process could end up running  on any CPU (unless pinned).

However you can get utilization % per-CPU. Use `/proc/stat`, and use the 4th field of each CPU to determine how idle that CPU is (See [`man 5 proc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and the `/proc/stat` section).
Basically read the value, sleep 1 second, read the value again, divide the difference by USER_HZ.